# How to check/compare the output of parallel GC threads and Conc GC threads ? How to settle down on the GC thread values?

Tags: java, performance, garbage-collection, jvm, heap-memory

I am using the CMS collector and running 4 JVMs.

1. I am tuning the jvm values based on analyzing the GC log, except for the
   value of GC threads. Should I tweak them for more stable Response times and Transactions per second ?
2. I am using the formula Parallel GC threads = No    of cores, as of
   now. Is there any other rules ?
3. Is there a way to view the results of the GC thread process.
4. Should I take a thread dump to view it ? Also any useful
       pointers/links to learn on how to analyze a thread dump ?

Comment: I would only set parameters you *know* help.  If you don't know if they help, don't include them. If the JVM is running on the machine alone, the default number of threads is likely to be the best value.

Comment: Is there an actual performance problem you're trying to solve? If so it should be part of your question.

Comment: I want to make the response time more stable, and under the SLA. What kind of justification/process should I follow to increase/decrease parallel/conc threads ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Really depends on your priorities. I would tune for best average response time if this is a web application.
2. That's a perfectly acceptable setting.
3. You can try -verbose:gc, -XX:+PrintGCDetails and -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps.
4. I recommend using JVisualVM with the VisualGC plugin. I have always found watching this to be far easier than reading logs. A thread dump is probably not going to help you with this.